# $(this).getAttribute is not a function when using $.each XML Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, loops, dom

I am looping through an XML document and trying to get the name attribute for each one, however Chrome keeps telling me that `$(this).getAttribute("name");` is not a function. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

I saw a similar post on this, but it was for passing `$(this)` in an `onclick` attribute in a button, not for iterating. Was hoping I could be enlightened on the matter.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
<hotel_group name="Pueblo Bonita" id="1">
    <hotel>
        <name>Pueblo Bonita 1</name>
        <location>
            <address>123 Deer St.</address>
            <city>Montego Bay</city>
            <state>St. Ann's Parish</state>
            <country>Jamaica</country>
        </location>
        <hotel_code>556</hotel_code>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <name>Pueblo Bonita 2</name>
        <location>
            <address>123 Caribou Dr.</address>
            <city>Negril</city>
            <state>Spanish Town</state>
            <country>Jamaica</country>
        </location>
        <hotel_code>555</hotel_code>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <name>Pueblo Bonita 3</name>
        <location>
            <address>30 Milsborough Dr</address>
            <city>Kingston</city>
            <state>Kingston</state>
            <country>Jamaica</country>
        </location>
        <hotel_code>552</hotel_code>
    </hotel>
</hotel_group>
</user>
```

JS:

```
            $(xml).find("hotel_group").each(function (k, v) {
                if (!hotelGroups) {
                    hotelGroups = [];
                }

                hotelGroups[k] = $(this).getAttribute("name");

            });
```

Comment: `getAttribute` is a native method, you probably need `.attr()`.

Comment: `hotelGroups[k] = this.getAttribute("name");` will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
hotelGroups[k] = $(this).attr("name");
```

I don't believe that `getAttribute` is a valid jQuery method.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I can't believe I forgot to use `.attr()` instead! I feel like such an idiot!

Comment: `this` is a DOM element node. So `this.getAttribute('name')` would work, too.

Comment: Yes, this is totally it.  Thx